# Xna Screenshot larger than 2048x2048 (reach profile)

Tags: c#, bitmap, xna, rendering

Need to know how to save a screenshot of the entire graphicsdevice backbuffer.
Using the Reach profile limits textures to 2048x2048.

*Loading bitmaps or from memory stream doesn't seem to be limited by this.

```
void ScreenshotFull()
    {
        Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color[] screenData = new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color[graphics.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth *
                                       graphics.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferHeight];

        RenderTarget2D screenShot = new RenderTarget2D(graphics.GraphicsDevice,2048, 2048);

        graphics.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(screenShot);
        Draw(new GameTime());
        graphics.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\Content\map\Full" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".png", FileMode.Create))
        {
            screenShot.SaveAsPng(stream, screenShot.Width, screenShot.Height);
            screenShot.Dispose();
        }

    }
```

Ideal screenshot would be 5632x2048. Can I target a rectangle or region with a 2nd RenderTarget?

Comment: Seeing as this is a Profile limitation (and I'm guessing you can't upgrade to HiDef), can't you just extract 1/3th of the back buffer, 3 times? I find it odd that the backbuffer can contain such a large image, if the profile only allows 2048x2048, but nontheless my suggestion should technically work. And then merge them together using for example the System.Drawing Bitmap API, or something similar?

Comment: That is actually what I went about doing. Using a camera matrix as a spritebatch.draw overload. Taking a picture of the 2048x2048 buffer, then moving the camera over 2048 x and taking another etc. Then stitching together. Not totally ideal, as being able to just pull a rectangle out of the buffer would be preferable.